# Logcat is empty and not showing details in android studio

Tags: android, logcat

I am trying to run an app in android studio and it is giving an error `Caused by: org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.CompilationErrorException: Compilation error. See log for more details` but when I open the Logcat, it is empty and not showing any details about the error. I have tried the invalidate caches and restart the app but it is not working and giving the same result. I have updated the dependencies in the gradle as well but nothing seems to be working. I don't know how to display the details in Logcat.

Answer (score 1):

**Logcat** is displaying logs from the android device - either physically attached one or from emulator. https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/logcat

You have a **compilation error** - before even launching application on the deivce, as such you are interested in Build output from your computer instead, in **Build Window**: https://developer.android.com/studio/run#gradle-console